# Where do the differences between render and baked texture come from and how to minimize them?

Tags: texture-baking, lighting

I'm playing with baked textures and do not understand the lighting differences between a pure render and a render using pre-baked lighting. The setup is simple:

[image: cycles render of a cube on a plane]

> cycles render of a cube on a plane

[image: cycles render with pre-baked textures]

> cycles render with pre-baked textures

[image: differences between these two images]

> differences between these two images

There are subtle differences of lighting between these two renders, but for more complex scence with more intense light, the differences become more important.

I'm guessing it can be due to color management (RGB / filmic) but I do not find relevant documentation about the proper way to do.